# Java how to use radio button to start an action and been able to click another button

Tags: java, user-interface, jbutton, jradiobutton

I am trying to make 2 radio buttons in one class working so that when they are selected it will allow for JButtons in another class to be pressed.

In other words, if I do not press the radio button I cannot press the buttons in the other class and change the color of the button in the other class.

I do not have the code although I was thinking about adding multiple action listeners both classes, i tried getters and setters but nothing happens, and I can't make it work.

I tried to use a string from the radio button eg:

```
If(btn.equals("w")){

Some string = "w"

}else{

Some string = "b"

}
```

and then set the string and get it in the other class but not working. Is there a way to make it work where you press one of the two radio buttons and then the other JButtons are available to click? How would you do that?

Answer (score 0):

This code will enable all of the radio buttons in the second group once any of the radio buttons of the first group becomes selected.

```
public class RadioButtonDemo extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new RadioButtonDemo().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public RadioButtonDemo() {
        super("Swing JRadioButton Demo");

        JRadioButton option1 = new JRadioButton("Linux 1");
        JRadioButton option2 = new JRadioButton("Windows 1");
        JRadioButton option3 = new JRadioButton("Macintosh 1");

        JRadioButton option4 = new JRadioButton("Linux 2");
        JRadioButton option5 = new JRadioButton("Windows 2");
        JRadioButton option6 = new JRadioButton("Macintosh 2");

        ButtonGroup group1 = new ButtonGroup();
        ButtonGroup group2 = new ButtonGroup();

        ActionListener listener = new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (((JRadioButton) e.getSource()).isSelected()) {
                    Enumeration<AbstractButton> elements = group2.getElements();
                    while (elements.hasMoreElements()) {
                        JRadioButton button = (JRadioButton) elements.nextElement();
                        button.setEnabled(true);
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        option1.addActionListener(listener);
        option2.addActionListener(listener);
        option3.addActionListener(listener);

        option4.setEnabled(false);
        option5.setEnabled(false);
        option6.setEnabled(false);

        group1.add(option1);
        group1.add(option2);
        group1.add(option3);

        group2.add(option4);
        group2.add(option5);
        group2.add(option6);

        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        add(option1);
        add(option2);
        add(option3);

        add(option4);
        add(option5);
        add(option6);


        pack();
    }
}
```

In the code where you change the color of the buttons, you might first check if it's enabled or not. Or if that's done from a UI element, you could disable that as well, depending on your needs.

Comment: That's good, but probably you have guessed that I am a noob, the JButton is in another class, do I have to use ActionListen inheritance to get the JButton in the other class to work?

Comment: Can't you make a method in that class that you can call from here?
If not, can you provide an SSCCE? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22754/sscce-how-to-provide-examples-for-programming-questions

Comment: No unfortunately I can't although I think I found the solution, I ll post it if I can